# Out of memory when using interp1. Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory

I have two arrays of a large number of elements that matlab can store. The problem comes when I try to use the function interp1 to interpolate using them. There is an error saying "out of memory - Error in interp1 (line 122)
    if any(diff(X)<0)"
What are my options?

```
    time; % Vector, length(time)=91542016
    Results; % Vector with the results for each time step, length(Results)=91542016
    A=1:1:(10^7); %Vector of positions in which I want to interpolate
    E=interp1(time,Results,A,'previous'); %Vector in which I want to store the interpolation
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using?

Comment: Depending on the type of interpolation you want to do (linear?), you may be able to use a loop. It will be slow, but memory-efficient

Comment: I want "previous" type interpolation

Comment: `time` and `Results` need 730 MB of RAM each, and `A` and `E` take another 80MB each, which gives a total of about 1.6GB + some overhead. Do you have more than 2GB RAM? Do you have any other large vectors in your memory?

Comment: can you not consider parts of `A` at a time?

Comment: The problem remains even if A has length 10 rather than 10^7. So dividing in different "As" does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your arrays from `'double'` to `'single'`. Then you will be using half as much memory.

Comment: If I do this I obtain the next error "Error using griddedInterpolant.The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized version:

```
n = numel(time);
%concatenate time and A and find index of sorted elements
[~, idx] = sort([time A]);
%n (variable length) categories created ,
%each element of time form a category
category = cumsum(idx <= n);
%determine which categories elements of A belong to 
idx_Results = category(idx > n);
out = Results(idx_Results);
```